Ascent trajectory Non Stagnation Point wall temperature Space Shuttle External tank
Are there any available data on the Space Shuttle External Tank wall temperatures, for the points and surfaces other than the stagnation point? I found an interesting paper here -> https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19910001724/downloads/19910001724.pdf but I doesn't seem to comprehend the ranges of temperatures the external walls experienced during ascent trajectory. Are there any documents or experiments where they tested this?
Considering the aluminium alloy tank and the Spray-on-foam-insulation, could it have been a more efficient design to go with steel like 304 or 316?

What kind of efficiency are you asking about? Weight, cost, ease of manufacturing, thermal, something else?

Weighing in all the factors. Of course weight wise Aluminium makes sense. ut for manufacturing, thermal and cost (?), doesnt Stainless Steel pose to be the better option? In any case, any data points on the wall temperatures reached on the shuttle external tank  on ascent

I found the answer through two other papers talkin about the requirements on the insulation.
https://www.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/114022main_tps_fs.pdf
http://www.nasa-klass.com/Curriculum/Get_Training%201/ET/RDG_ET-Additional/ETStatistics.pdf
They are indicative and not definitive.
The temperature on the walls on ascent reaches somewhere around 2000 degrees F.
